# Python-Django cannot interpret the id in an URL and give "<built-in function id>" instead of redirecting on the rigth page

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a simple app that creates Events and add attendees to them built with Django 1.8. I work on a virtualenv with python3.
When I create an event, I'm redirected to the detail page of this event and I have now the possibility to add some attendees. But when I add one, django cannot redirect me to the page of the event, cause it cannot interpret the id and gives me `<built-in function id>`.

> **My app Event :**
>
> *models.py*

```
class Event(models.Model):

name = models.CharField("Event title", max_length=255)
organizer = models.ForeignKey(User)
attendees = models.ManyToManyField(User, verbose_name="Attendees", blank=True, 
    through="EventAttendees", related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_attendees")


def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('event:detail', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})


def delete_url(self):
    return reverse('event:delete', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})


def update_url(self):
    return reverse('event:update', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})


def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Event'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Events'


class EventAttendees(models.Model):
event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
attendee = models.ForeignKey(User)


def delete_url(self):
    return "/event/%i/attendee/%i/delete/" % (self.event.id, self.attendee.id)

class Meta:
    unique_together = (
        'event',
        'attendee',
        )
```

> forms.py

```
class EventForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Event
    fields = ('name',)


class EventAttendeesForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = EventAttendees
    fields = ('event', 'attendee',)


def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(EventAttendeesForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['event'].widget = HiddenInput()

    if 'event' in self.initial:
        attendees = [user.pk for user in self.initial['event'].attendees.all()]
        self.fields['attendee'].queryset=User.objects.exclude(pk__in = attendees)
```

> **views.py**

```
class EventCreateView(CreateView):
model = Event 
form_class = EventForm
template_name = 'evenement/event/create.html'


def form_valid(self, form):
    obj = form.save(commit=False)

    o = User.objects.get(username=self.request.user)
    obj.organizer = o
    obj.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect(obj.get_absolute_url())


def delete_attendee(request, event_id, attendee_id):
if request.method == 'POST':
    event = Event.objects.get(pk = event_id)
    attendee = User.objects.get(pk = attendee_id)

    to_be_deleted = EventAttendees.objects.get(
        event = event, 
        attendee = attendee)
    to_be_deleted.delete()
    if request.is_ajax():
        return HttpResponse("Ok")
return HttpResponseRedirect('/event/%s/detail/' % event_id)

class EventDetailView(DetailView):
model = Event
template_name = 'evenement/event/details.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(EventDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    form = EventAttendeesForm(initial = {'event':self.object})
    attendees = [user.pk for user in self.object.attendees.all()]
    form.fields['attendee'].queryset = User.objects.exclude(pk__in = attendees)
    form.fields['event'].widget = HiddenInput()
    context['form'] = form
    return context


def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = EventAttendeesForm(self.request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/event/%s/detail/' %id)
    else:
        return render(request, 'evenement/event/details.html', {'event': form.instance.event, 'form': form})
```

I think that the problem is located in the function post of the class EventDetailView, here

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('/event/%s/detail/' %id)
```

Python cannot interpret `%id`

I wanted to join the app, but I don't know how to.
Many thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to actually get the id of the item, which you're not doing.

```
if form.is_valid():
    obj = form.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/event/%s/detail/' % obj.id)
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel Roseman. If I get the id like how you propose, I get the id of the attendee that I added, not the id of the event to which I added attendee. I've tried that and it not worked.

Comment: Er, OK. I'm not sure why you want to redirect then, because that's the current URL. But you can get it from `self.kwargs['pk']`.

Comment: This solution works. Thank you for your help. A friend propose another solution to me. return HttpResponseRedirect('#') that also works. Could you please tell me what's the difference between these 2 solutions and what's the best according to you?